# Поиск медианы и удаление элементов

Tags: javascript

Не могу в цикле удалить все элементы массива.

Медиана — это такое число выборки, что ровно половина из элементов выборки больше него, а другая половина меньше него.

Получается проблемма закулючается в том что не все элементы убираются в дилнныйх массивах, при переборе и удалении. Не знаю чего может не хватать, вроде бы по моей логике всё должно работать, но уберает всего несколько элементов из длинных массивов.

В случае же с короткими массивами всё отлично работает. Подскажите где я что не правильно сделал.

```js
function median(data) {
    var count = 0;
    
    data.sort((a, b) => a - b);



    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data.length % 2 === 0) {
            data.pop();
            data.shift();
        } else if (data.length % 2 === 1) {
            data.pop();
            data.shift();
            }
        if (data.length === 2) {
            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
                count = (data[0] + data[1]);
                return count / 2;
            }
        }
    }








    return data;
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
console.log(median([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]));
console.log(median([0,7,1,8,4,9,5,6,2,3]));
console.log(median([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
console.log(median([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы модифицируете массив, по которому бежите. Не знаю, зачем вам вообще цикл, достаточно проверить, что если чилсо элементов четное, то взять два из середины и усреднить, если нет, то взять центральную чиселку.

Если же исправлять ваше то вот пример:

```js
function median(data) {
    var count = 0;
    
    data.sort((a, b) => a - b);

    do {
          data.pop();
          data.shift();
    } while (data.length > 2)
    
    if (data.length === 2) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            count = (data[0] + data[1]);
            return count / 2;
        }
    }

    return data[0];
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
console.log(median([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]));
console.log(median([0,7,1,8,4,9,5,6,2,3]));
console.log(median([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
console.log(median([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
function median(data) {
  data.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  if (data.length % 2) {
    return data[Math.floor(data.length / 2)];
  } else {
    return (data[data.length / 2] + data[data.length / 2 - 1]) / 2;
  }
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
console.log(median([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]));
console.log(median([0, 7, 1, 8, 4, 9, 5, 6, 2, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]));
console.log(median([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Но куда логичнее было бы сделать так:

```js
const median = arr => {
  const arrayHalf = arr.length / 2
  const sorted = [].concat(arr).sort((a,b) => a - b)
  
  return arr.length % 2 === 0
  ? (sorted[arrayHalf] + sorted[arrayHalf + 1]) / 2
  : sorted[~~(arrayHalf)]
}

console.log(median([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
console.log(median([3, 1, 2, 5, 3]));
console.log(median([1, 300, 2, 200, 1]));
console.log(median([3, 6, 20, 99, 10, 15]));
console.log(median([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]));
console.log(median([0,7,1,8,4,9,5,6,2,3]));
console.log(median([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]));
console.log(median([2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]));
```

Comment: Честно говоря, твой прошлый код был более читабельный (по крайней мере для меня). Я просто сравнительно недавно начал учить JS.

Comment: Если четное количество элементов - берешь две средние цифры и делишь пополам, если нет - берешь из серединки чиселку.

concat не обязателен, просто так не меняется начальный массив.

Comment: Можно вопрос, ну это так для себя, сколько ты учил JS, Что бы так быстро решать такие задачи. Просто я над ней сидел 1 день, а потом психанул и сюда написал.

Comment: Да не так уж и много. Задача то не сложная, просто иногда хорошо помогает свежий взгляд со стороны. :)